# Is there a sort order for success messages?

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, session

I use `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event to check whether the particular product is available for the zipcode (which is already stored in customer session).

I show a notice message if it's not available using

```
$checkoutSession->addNotice("Sorry this product cannot be shipped to the specified PINCODE: ".$customerPincode);
```

I show success message when it is available

```
$checkoutSession->addSuccess("This product is available for the specified PINCODE: ".$customerPincode);
```

but my problem is this:

[image]

my custom message should come next to default success message. How can I do this?

Comment: You should look into overriding Mage_Core_Block_Messages::getGroupedHtml if you want to do some custom logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the class `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract` that is the actual class providing this functionality to all of the other 'sessions' you can see in the `addMessage` method for example it only accepts a single argument called `$message`.

This argument is pushed into a Varien Object which acts as a simple array (with some added functions). This means that whoever pushes their message first will be displayed first.